# Comic about fighting space pirates which involves abducting a soldier from world war 1 or 2

Tags: story-identification, comics

When I was a kid in the early 90s, Latvia had just regained independence from the USSR and was trying to get on its feet. Western things were few and far between and were highly praised. During this era some publishers tried translating and reprinting some western comics - usually some 3rd rate ones where copyright was dirt cheap.

I believe I had one such comic book. It was obviously the first one in a series because it just set the story up and didn't go anywhere. I never saw any other issues of it and I don't even remember the name. I do remember the story though.

First there was a scene where some intergalactic council was discussing the latest news about space pirates. It seems that the pirates were being unacceptably successful and people were starting to suspect that they had access to time travel (or maybe teleport?) technology.

Then the scene changes and we see some soldiers during World War 1 or 2. They are walking through some wilderness and one of them is begrudging losing to another soldier at cards or dice or something like that. I think he owed him a lot now and he didn't want to pay up. So instead he tried to isolate and silently kill the other guy. My memory is a bit murky on what happened then but I think he didn't succeed.

A bit later the scene changed again. The second soldier woke up in an unfamiliar room and was wondering if he was in a hospital. Then someone came in and he was surprised to see that they looked exactly like him. The newcomer explained that it was a matter of common courtesy to assume the appearance of the person you're trying to welcome.

And around there the story stopped.

Does anyone recognize this story? I'm curious as to what happened next. :)